# Can I program nanobots to behave like sperm and fool an egg?

Tags: biology, nanotechnology

In short I'm looking at creating an artificial sperm smart enough to fertilize an egg and develop into an embryo, so that would mean the sperm must have some means of carrying information similar to DNA and interact with it. I think of it as a parasite scavenging for necessary material from the egg and transform the egg into an embryo capable of developing into a design baby, am I being naïve or that's just scratching the surface using science? btw everything is customizable so you can set the skin pigmentation, hair color, pupil color, quintuplets, conjoins, you get the drift.

Comment: Make the opposition question in another post, only 1 question at once.

Comment: @Ekaen: amended ;D

Comment: I don't get it. Are you asking how to create sperm that is just like normal sperm? If you are aiming for the question in the title, how can someone answer what kind of programs could be executed by a machine you invented and didn't say anything about but the name? Btw how is regular sperm not a 'nanobot'? (Apart from the scale)

Comment: @Raditz_35: no, I'm asking if a nanobot can fool an egg into thinking it is a sperm and then manipulate the egg in some way that transform it into an embryo.

Comment: The egg doesn't think. It doesn't need to be fooled. I still think you are literally just asking if you can create (artificial if you insist) sperm. The answer is: yes of course because life isn't magic

Comment: @Raditz_35: good one.

Comment: Is there any chance that in your world there is what is sometimes called a life force or apparently entelchy (just learned that word, thanks!): https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_%28esotericism%29?wprov=sfla1 ? This would be the way to explain why it doesnt work. Otherwise you can do anything biological with sufficient tech the artificial way

Comment: Nanobots aren't (yet) real, so just *take for granted* that the level of science and technology in your story is advanced enough to do what you want.  Readers will accept it, since nanobots are -- essentially -- modern technomagic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some times ago there have been reports of [synthetic sperm cells being created](https://www.ft.com/content/0f9b51d6-c565-11e7-b30e-a7c1c7c13aab)

> Experiments with mice show that synthetic sperm and eggs can be created using stem cell technology.

Just get the right proteins on the surface, so that the egg will be lured into letting the bot in, and have the correct DNA available to trigger cellular multiplication.

Comment: Always when I'm debating with the op to see if he comes to the obvious conclusion himself, you seem to come in and just spell it out for him/her. Next time I should really try your approach ;).

Answer (score 4):

Simpler than creating a nanobot is to take existing sperm cells, remove their original DNA and replace it with DNA which contains the predesigned genetic information at the position of the respective gene loci. This is more or less feasible with existing technology in molecular biology (as L.Dutch already pointed out) - the main problem being that it is cost intensive and that cutting the DNA in *all* the right spots and placing *all* the predesigned genes in exactly the correct places is a tough challenge. An even if all this works out correctly, during the mitotic process when reuniting the two halves of DNA into a full organism's DNA and reproducing it many times to create an embryo still underlies the typical biological chance of mistakes in the repoduction.

Also by controlling the sperm you do not control the majority of information inherited by the embryo. You cannot control the inforation inherited from the motherly DNA. Some traits have a dominant inheritance meaning that the DNA from one of the genes would always overrule the information of the other.
Also, mitochondria - formerly bacteria, now cell organella repsonsible for producing the cell's energy for living and 'working' - contain their own DNA and are only inherited from the egg cell.